# Get the email of the author of the currently being edited post in Gutenberg frontend

Tags: block-editor, rest-api

The title is my aim. I want to get the email of the author of the currently being edited post and show it to the user (in a side panel, but it could equally be in a block).

I have searched this site and found [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/412855/how-to-get-custom-user-meta-by-id-in-custom-gutenberg-block).

The first solution there is tantalising. Parts of it work e.g.

```
wp.data.select('core').getUser(2,{context:'view'})
```

gets me the user name of user with ID 2.

However; it doesn't get me the email and it doesn't get me the user id of the currently-being-edited post. The line:

```
wp.data.select('core').getUser(1,{'_fields':'first_name,last_name'})
```

just gives me undefined.

But I did learn from the first solution that when the post is loaded in the editor a call is made to a Users Rest API - it doesn't get the email of the user but probably I could get it this way - though this still does not give me the user id of the currently being edited post.

The second solution in this answer is the one I have gone with - I get the author email in the PHP and feed it to the front-end via a filter which modifies the Rest response.

But - I would still like to do this purely in the front end. The first step seems to be if I could get the user id of the author of the currently being edited post from the data store. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how can you get the ID and email address of the author of the currently being edited post:

```js
// Get the post author's ID.
let postAuthorId = wp.data.select( 'core/editor' ).getCurrentPostAttribute( 'author' );
/* or you can also use this:
let postAuthorId = wp.data.select( 'core/editor' ).getEditedPostAttribute( 'author' );
*/

// Get the post author's email.
let postAuthorEmail = wp.data.select( 'core' ).getUser( postAuthorId )?.email;

console.log( postAuthorId, postAuthorEmail );
```

**Note:** I used the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (i.e. `?.`) as in `?.email` because `getUser()` uses AJAX, so you may need to call it twice in order to see the proper user object/data.

As for the issue in question - "*However; it doesn't get me the email and it doesn't get me the user id of the currently-being-edited post*", that's because the `context` is `view`, therefore the REST API did not include the `email` field which is made available only to the context `edit`.

- See the row for the `email` field in the schema table at https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/users/#schema.
- `wp.data.select( 'core' ).getUser()` sets the default context to `edit`, so if you omitted the `context` prop or that you used `context:'edit'`, then you would have seen the `email` field in the object returned by that `getUser` function.

Comment: "getUser() uses AJAX, so you may need to call it twice" - that's horrible :-/ Is there a way to await the call, or give it a callback for when the request completes? (sorry, don't know the API; I guess [this is the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/data/data-core/)?)

Comment: Yes @Rup, that's the documentation, except that `getUser` wasn't added to the selector list there. But that function is a wrapper around `wp.data.select('core').getEntityRecord( 'root', 'user', <user ID> )` which returns `undefined` if the AJAX request has not yet been resolved. Therefore I don't think we can await the call (like we can with `window.fetch()`) because the selector/function doesn't return a `Promise`.

Comment: However, with the right approach, e.g. using [`useSelect`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-data/#useselect) in a component of a block, you would not need to worry about await-ing.. because once the AJAX request is complete, i.e. the data is ready, the component will automatically be notified so that it can display the data or do whatever necessary.

Comment: @Rup and Kropotkin as well, see my block's [index file here](https://gist.github.com/5ally/a35935bbaa5b3d913dcac5f27e163cce) for a sample implementation.

Comment: @SallyCJ - Thanks, got it. + thanks for the github example. I had to add support for author to register_post_type for my custom post. What I find interesting is select( 'core' ).getUser( currentAuthorId ) makes a Rest call to /wp/v2/users/ID - it knows it doesn't have the data in the store and so it makes the rest call. I guess this is a general principle. Thanks again.

Comment: getUser is undocumented: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/data/data-core/

Comment: Yes, that's why I said "*`getUser` wasn't added to the selector list there*", and it uses/calls `getEntityRecord()` (which fetches data from the REST API), and yes, for custom post types, the default [`supports`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#supports) values are just `title` and `editor`, so `author` should be manually added.